# ICAPM when assets' mean returns and variance-covariance matrix are not constant over time

Tags: macroeconomics, finance, asset-pricing, empirical-methods

The intertemporal capital asset pricing model (ICAPM), under the usual assumptions, produces a multifactor pricing model like [the one described in this question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/485/dealing-with-missing-data-when-testing-the-capm).

When and how would it be possible to test this result when the assets' mean returns and variance-covariance matrix of returns are not constant over time?